# Links in an iframe in a jQuery dialog do not open within the iframe

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, jquery-ui-dialog

By default, a link in an iframe should open within that iframe. But when I use jQuery dialog to load an iframe and then click a link within it, it always opens in a new tab, NOT the iframe. This happens even if I use jQuery to handle the link click and do something like this:

```
$("a").click(function ()  <---this is in the load event of the frame window
{
    var href = $(this).attr("href");

    location.href = href;

    return false;
});
```

This happens in multiple browsers, so I think it's intentional, but I'm not sure why, or how to make this behave properly.

Comment: isn't the `window` object within an iframe in fact the window of the iframe document, NOT the parent window?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: everything here is within the iframe, although i can see how using a selector like `#myiframe` is confusing. I'll change that.

Comment: Ok, I have removed my comments then as they are no longer relevant.